# Multiple forms on page, minimal validation functions

Tags: javascript, html, validation

Without using JQuery, I have multiple forms on a page, without re-writing loads of functions, can you help me with this?

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validPhone()   {
                            if(document.all.[phoneVar].value.length <= 7)
                            alert("You must enter a valid phone number");
                            document.all.[phoneVar].focus() ;
                            return false;
                        }


</script>
</head><body>

<script type="text/javascript">
function checkThisParticularForm()  {
    var phoneVar = document.GetElementById('phone').value; //set element id
    validPhone(); //this calls the validPhone function
}
</script>

<form action="./logging.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="NewCallForm" onsubmit="checkThisParticularForm();">
<input type="text" class="textbox" id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" value="" />
<input type="submit"  value="Submit Details">
</form>

</body></html>
```

On submitting each form, I'm wanting it to validate certain fields, in this example, the phone number, but I'm wanting to create 1 main function that can be called on by other forms so it contains a variable `[phoneVar]` which I'm trying to declare before that function is called.
Sorry if this is simple, I'm not good with JavaScript, any help/pointers appreciated.

Comment: So is this just a client side check? Because you should still validate on the server side before saving the form information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider writing a validation library and using HTML5 `data-foo` attributes to do all the dirty work:

```
<form ...>
    <input type="text" name="foo"
        data-validation-required="true">

    <input type="text" name="phone"
        data-validation-required="true"
        data-validation-required-message="The phone number is required"
        data-validation-format="^\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}"
        data-validation-format-message="Please enter a valid phone number">

</form>
```

And create a JavaScript library to do the validation:

```
var Validator = {
    init: function() {
        document.documentElement.addEventListener("submit", this.handleSubmit.bind(this), false);
    },

    handleSubmit: function(event) {
        var form = event.target.form || event.target,
            requiredFields = form.querySelectorAll("[data-validation-required=true"),
            formattedFields = form.querySelectorAll("[data-validation-format]");

        if (!this.validateRequiredFields(requiredFields)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        else if (!this.validateFormats(formattedFields)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    },

    validateRequiredFields: function(fields) {
        var regex = /^\s*%/, i = 0,
            success = true;

        for (i; i < fields.length; i++) {
            if (regex.test(fields[i].value)) {
                this.showMessage(fields[i].getAttribute("data-valiation-required-message") || "This field is required", fields[i]);
                success = false;
            }
        }
    }

    validateFormats: function(fields) {
        var format, field,
            i = 0, length = fields.length,
            success = true;

        for (i; i < length; i++) {
            field = fields[i];
            format = new RegExp(field.getAttribute("data-validation-format"));

            if (!format.test(field.value)) {
                this.showMessage(field.getAttribute("data-validation-format-message"), field);
                success = false;
            }
        }

        return success;
    },

    showMessage: function(message, field) {
        field.classList.add("invalid");
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        span.className = "validation-error";
        span.innerHTML = message;
        field.parentNode.insertBefore(span, field);
    }
};

Validator.init();
```

That's all you need for the whole page because `document.documentElement` is the `<html>` tag. And since `submit` events bubble up the document tree, you only need one submit handler.

(Note: this is untested code, but should give you the basic idea)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way to do this, but at first you've to wrap all the forms within a `div id="allforms"`.

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('allforms').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
        var pn = e.target.phoneNumber;
        if (pn.value.length <= 7) {
            alert("You must enter a valid phone number");
            pn.focus() ;
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
}
```

The idea is, that `submit` event bubbles to the `div`, and only you need to do, is to listen `submit` events on that `div`. This is called event delegation.

`e.target` in the listener function refers to an element, which triggered the event. In this case it is the `form` element which is meant to be sumitted.

Since `e.target` is a `form`, you can refer directly to the named `form` elements. `document.all` is IE-specific, and obsoleted in IE11.

`e.preventDefault()` prevents the default action after event, in this case it prevents the form to be submitted.

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d3nCB/).

<sup>If you need support for IE<9 too, please let me know, I'll add the code.</sup>